# Parse error on input ‘Just’

Tags: haskell

I have this code:

```
myF :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> (Int, Int)
myF mb1 mb2 =
  let var1 = case mb1 of
    Just x -> x
    Nothing -> 123

  let var2 = case mb2 of
    Just x -> x
    Nothing -> 456

  let var3 = (var1 + var2 ) * 333
  (var2, var3)
```

It gives me a compilation error "parse error on input ‘Just’". How to fix it?

Comment: I think you are missing the `in` keyword -> `let var3 = (var1 + var2 ) * 333 in  (var2, var3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Daniel already said, the contents of a `let` binding needs to be more indented than its patterns. Also, you need `let … in` outside of a `do` block. If you really want to use three `let`'s you would end up with something like this:

```
myF :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> (Int, Int)
myF mb1 mb2 =
  let var1 = case mb1 of
       Just x  -> x
       Nothing -> 123
  in let var2 = case mb1 of
          Just x  -> x
          Nothing -> 456
     in let var3 = (var1 + var2 ) * 333
        in (var2, var3)
```

However, multiple `let … in` can usually get refactored into a single `let … in`. Note that even a version with a single `let … in` exhibits a violation of the don't-repeat-yourself rule:

```
myF :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> (Int, Int)
myF mb1 mb2 =
  let var1 = case mb1 of  -- (1)
       Just x  -> x
       Nothing -> 123
      var2 = case mb1 of  -- (2)
       Just x  -> x
       Nothing -> 456
      var3 = (var1 + var2 ) * 333
  in (var2, var3)
```

You use (almost) the same code twice in `(1)` and `(2)`. Also, you probably missed the introduced error in `(2)`, where I used `mb1` instead of `mb2`. You can make this a lot more readable with `fromMaybe` (in `Data.Maybe`):

```
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)
-- fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a

myF :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> (Int, Int)
myF mb1 mb2 =
  let var1 = fromMaybe 123 mb1
      var2 = fromMaybe 456 mb2
      var3 = (var1 + var2) * 333
  in (var2, var3)
```

#### Exercises

- Without looking at its source, try to implement `fromMaybe` yourself.
- Rewrite `myF`, this time using `where` instead of `let … in` (just to get more familiar with Haskell's syntax).

Comment: is it mandatory to use only a single "let" in such the cases?

Comment: @OskarK.: Well, you can use multiple, I'll edit my answer. But you don't want to. Don't confuse Haskell's `let` with ES6 or Rust ones.

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems:

1. Both `let` and `of` introduce blocks. For things to parse correctly, the patterns in the `case`/`of` block must be indented more than the patterns in the `let` block.
2. Because you are not in a `do` block, each `let` must be accompanied by an `in`. You can reduce the total number of `in`s needed by using just one `let` block.

Combined, this gets you:

```
myF :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> (Int, Int)
myF mb1 mb2 =
  let var1 = case mb1 of
        Just x -> x
        Nothing -> 123

      var2 = case mb2 of
        Just x -> x
        Nothing -> 456

      var3 = (var1 + var2 ) * 333
  in (var2, var3)
```

Comment: but I need 3 variables "var1, var2 and var3" and return a tuple of them as a result, how can I use only one "let"?

Comment: By typing let only once.  You don't need to type `let`separately for each variable, a new indented line suffices.

Comment: @OskarK. You may of course use `let` 3 times -- you will simply need to include `in` 3 times as well.